# Cannot create any objects in a folder after setting up a new workflow state in Plone

Tags: permissions, workflow, plone

I have some issues with the Plone 4.3.1 permission settings. But I have come long way with the existing documentation and [Aspelli's book](http://www.martinaspeli.net/plone-book). But I cannot figure out why I am unable to create any object in a folder, even as Site Administrator, after setting up a workflow-state that grants permissions to a specific user role.

The workflow-state is called "Show_External" and the permissions that are set through the Permissions tab of the workflow state are as follows:

```
Permission                  Acquire     Site Admin    Ext_Supplier
Access content information     -            X            X
List folder contents           -            X            X
Modify portal content          -            X            X
View                           -            X            X
```

I do not want to "Acquire" any permissions because the new role is for an external supplier that has no business with anything else on this particular site.

The result - much against what I expected - is that no one can create any object. The option is shown in the interface, but any attempt results in `Error Please correct the indicated errors.`. No errors are indicated however.

What I can do is make the objects (folders  and files) in another folder and then copy paste them to the folder that is set in the workflow-state. Stranger still, once I copy the folder as a subfolder to the External Supplier folder a can add files through QuickUpload, but not by selecting "Add file".

What am I missing in my understanding of the permissions?

Answer (score 1):

You likely ran into a bug, which was fixed just now:

http://plone.293351.n2.nabble.com/Bug-on-sharing-page-upgrade-plone-app-workflow-to-2-1-6-td7566655.html

Does upgrading p.a.workflow help?

Comment: Unfortunately the update did not solve my problem. I have toggled the states to make sure that they are updated (on top of the 'update permissions' button in the portal_workflow). But still soon as I remove "Acquire" from the permission settings I loose the ability to add or edit objects. The issue does not register as an error in any log that I can find, and I wish I knew how to trace what is happening back to the setting that causes this behaviour.

Comment: Could iw.rejectanonymous have something to do with it? I have already tried to disable it and run through my workflow permission updates again, without effect. But perhaps the impact of iw.rejectanonymous makes runs deeper.

Answer (score 0):

The solution in the end was to install plone.app.workflowmanager. For some reason that I do not understand the "Permission Roles" that show up under the workflow states created through ZMI did not have either the "Add" or the Review Permission.

Correcting the permissions through the workflow manager solved the problems.

If you try it out then note that you need to check the "Advanced Mode" checkbox to be able to update the permission settings on existing objects.

Having dregdged through ZMI screens for the past few days, the Workflow Manager is a great improvement! Very nicely done.

If someone can still explain why there is a difference between the permissions that I set through ZMI and the workflow manager I would very much like to know (feel free to edit this answer, marked as "community wiki").